# Whats wrong with this version of functor(Prolog)?

Tags: prolog

I tried to write functor inbuilt in Prolog. This is my version:

```
lenlist(L,N) :- lenlist(L,0,N).
lenlist([],N,N).
lenlist([_|T],P,N) :- P1 is P+1 , lenlist(T,P1,N).

functor1(Term,F,N) :- Term =.. [F|Args] , lenlist(Args,N).
```

Here is a sample execution of Prolog inbuilt functor

```
?- functor(Term,f,6).  
Term = f(_G247, _G248, _G249, _G250, _G251, _G252)
```

Now if I execute the same query with `functor1` I get an exception

```
?- functor1(Term,f,6).
ERROR: =../2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
   Exception: (8) _G180=..[f|_G248] ? creep
```

What's wrong with the `functor1` function I wrote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that Args is not yet instantiated for =.. . Try putting lenlist/3 before it.

BTW, you could also use the built-in length/2.

Comment: functor1(Term,F,N) :- length(Args,N) , Term =.. [F|Args],!. 
---This works

Comment: Well I had to put a cut , for it not go and seek other solution.But this ideally should return with "no" when pressed for more solutions. Without cut it goes out of stack

Answer (score 4):

**starblue** is correct, but in order to write your version of `functor1/3` properly, I recommend that you consider the 'modes' it requires:

1. Inspect an *existing term* (i.e., *not* a variable) for it's functor/arity.
2. *Build* a term (assigning it to a variable) from a functor/arity description.
3. All other modes are irrelevant/incorrect.

With these three cases in mind, try the following. First, case (1): extract the Functor and Arity from an existing Term:

```
functor1(Term, Functor, Arity) :-
    \+ var(Term), !,
    % inspect existing term
    Term =.. [Functor|ArgList],
    length(ArgList, Arity).
```

Note that we exclude other cases if the Term argument is not a variable with the cut (!). Secondly, case (2): construct a Term from a Functor and an Arity:

```
functor1(Term, Functor, Arity) :-
    var(Term), 
    atom(Functor),
    number(Arity), !,
    % build a term
    length(ArgList, Arity),
    Term =.. [Functor|ArgList].
```

Note that the mode checking performed by the subgoals prior to the cut (!) encapsulate the guard (precondition) for this case. Finally, all other cases (i.e., those where we need to construct a term, but don't have a functor, arity or either) are invalid (3):

```
functor1(_Term, _Functor, _Arity) :-
    throw('Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated.').
```

Alternatively, for this last case, this whole clause can be omitted to achieve the behavior that `functor/1` returns false for the remaining argument bindings it will cover.

Also note that this version relies on built-ins `length/2`, `var/1`, `number/1` and `atom/1` (among others), which are present in SWI-PROLOG.

Comment: +1 for attention to detail. This is seriously an *excellent* answer.